# Getting the permutation of a list in haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, permutation

at the university we just started learning haskell. So I am really new to that whole "functional programming"-world...

I already had to implement a function that lets you insert a value at each point in a list. It is already running and works like this.

```
-- Inserts a value of type a in each position of a list and returns a list of all those lists
insert :: a -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

My task now is to implement a function that calculates all permutations of a given list.
So I thought I could use the already working `insert`-function and do it like this:

```
perms :: [a] -> [[a]]
perms [] = [[]]
perms (x:xs) = insert x perms(xs)
```

But unfortunately it is not working. I am not sure but I think the problem might be, that the `insert`-function creates a list of lists and thereby on recursion a list of lists of lists of ...  which leads to a problem when recalling the insert function recursivly, because `x`  is not fitting into those cascading lists.
Can somebody help me with this just a little bit? Thank you very much :)

Comment: Since `perms xs` returns a list of lists, you can only call `insert x` on one of the lists at a time, then combine the results. Consider taking advantage of the list monad, `perms xs >>= insert x`.

Comment: `insert x perms(xs) ` calls `insert` with three arguments: `x`, `perms`, `xs`. The parentheses are redundant. If you want to be sure to call `perms` with `xs`, use `(perms xs)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Alright... I found the solution with the help from [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64993140/getting-the-permutation-of-a-list-in-haskell#comment114903963_64993140). My Code is now running and looks like this:

```
perms :: [a] -> [[a]]
perms [] = [[]]
perms (x:xs) = insertEverywhere x (perms xs)
  where insertEverywhere :: a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
        insertEverywhere e [[]]   = [[e]]
        insertEverywhere e [x]    = (insert e x)
        insertEverywhere e (l:ls) = (insert e l) ++ (insertEverywhere e ls)
```